# Nested for loop visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am getting a list of directories from my app.config file, and then using the current directory I am in, I am combing through these directories searching for any .ini files and adding them to a drop down list. I am able to iterate through the first directory, but not through any of the other ones. Is there something wrong with my loop structure?

This is my Load method

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                       Handles MyBase.Load

  'Get the current directory
  Dim curDir As String
  curDir = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory

  'Get the directory paths to populate dropdown with INIs
  Dim paths As String()
  paths = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DIRECTORY_LIST").Split(",")

  'Nested for loop to cycle through the directories and add the .inis to dropdown for each
  For Each path As String In paths
    PartNumberTextBox.Items.Add(Replace(path, "\ini\", "") + "----------------------------")
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(curDir + path, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ini")
      Dim iniFileName As String = Replace(foundFile, curDir, "")
      PartNumberTextBox.Items.Add(iniFileName)
    Next
  Next
```

Image of dropdown, notice the other directories (which have ini files) don't show

[image]

Comment: Well, what's the value of `curDir + path`?  Is it a valid path?

Comment: Yes its a valid path, ive added an image that shows it working for the first directory

Comment: Are you asking why it is not finding the files recursively, in nested folders??

Comment: No, I am asking why inside for loop only seems to run once, and then doesn't run for the remaining iterations (directories)

Comment: Also, it doesnt seem to find any .ini files in nested folders also!

Comment: Code seems to work.  Maybe you don't have INI files in that directory.  In your GetFiles call, you are specifying SearchTopLevelOnly.

Comment: Could there be swallowed exceptions ? I would try putting the loop in a try/catch block..